# Time limited access with JS and Stripe

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, stripe-payments

I'm new to develop things in JS and i was wandering aroud Stripe techno.

I have a project to make a site where you can buy credits, let's say for 24h, to use for accessing extended functionnality (not a pr0n site :) )

Things i want to do is:

- User buys `credit` (for 24h, 48h, 1 week)
- The credits are `stackable` (if I buy 2x 24h I have 48h)
- When user's credit hits 0, sends a command to client side to "close access"

All stack is in `JS client side` and `NodeJS server side`.

I have no clue how to develop this with Stripe integration. Does Stripe have a function to do this, or should i use the token they return and build a thing with `Redis` and `EXPIRY keys` ?

Thanks for reading and in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your business, you need to use 2 features of stripe:

1. Subscription feature (https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions/quickstart). It is used to charge your customer in period time you defined. Beside of that, you are able to create a plan for recurring billing.
2. Events feature 
   (https://stripe.com/docs/api#events). The stripe system will notify you any events what made changes on your account. Let's say when the subscription of the customer is expired. The stripe system will raise an alert to url you registered to receive the events.

Hope information above will give you more ideas to work on the stripe system.